# How to uninstall python3 on mac?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I would like to uninstall all the python3 version and folders in my mac. How can I do?

For instance, if I type

```
which python3
/usr/bin/python3
```

and I tried to install `jupyter` and If I type

```
jupyter-notebook
-bash: /usr/local/bin/jupyter-notebook: /usr/local/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3.9: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

I would like to uninstall `python3` and install it again

Comment: You can find the answer in **super user** form.

Comment: It seems `/usr/local/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3.9` is already uninstalled, based on your error.

Comment: Did you do `/usr/bin/python3 -m pip install jupyter` (the recommended way to run pip)? Otherwise, your standalone `pip` or `pip3` is not associated with the python executable you think it is